# Get previous one item and next two item of current item in PHP. with max limit and current index only using for loop

Tags: php

i need to get previous value and next two values of a current_selected_val with max value stating in the starting only. Currently I am using this and not getting actual results. Can someone please help me in this

```
<?php
$pager_max = 8;
$current = 3;
for($i = 1; $i <= $pager_max; $i++) {
    if ($i > ($current - $pager_max ) + 6 && $i < $current + 3) {
        echo $i . '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Here are the results which I wanted
If I select $current as
1 - **1** 2 3 4
2 - 1 **2** 3 4
3 - 2 **3** 4 5
4 - 3 **4** 5 6
5 - 4 **5** 6 7
6 - 5 **6** 7 8
7 - 5 6 **7** 8
8 - 5 6 7 **8**

If I change $pager_max to any other value, then behaviour should be same. I need to use only formulas but not any functions here. Thanks in advance

Comment: "I need to use only formulas but not any functions here" - that sounds like an arbitrary requirement

Comment: @ChrisHaas. Yes because need to keep the code in twig file and its for pagination

Comment: thank you for that explanation. Any time we hear what sounds like an arbitrary restriction, it helps to understand the reasons behind it. Your reason for not using functions make sense, however I think you could solve this by just writing a quick [custom extension](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/advanced.html). For instance, if lukas.j's answer works, I'd just wrap that into a custom Twig function called `createPaginationItems` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getValues(int $pager_max, int $current) {
  if ($current === 1) {
    return range(1, 4);
  } elseif ($current + 2 >= $pager_max) {
    return range($pager_max - 3, $pager_max);
  } else {
    return range($current - 1, $current + 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this function but I need to write the same in twig template. So functions cant keep in twig file.

Comment: You do not use the function in the template, you use the return value(s) of the function.